# Any way to know the custom keyboard frame in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I'm developing a custom keyboard extension and noticed when I call `self.inputView.frame.size.width` in either `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, it returns 0 or an incorrect number. Only in `viewDidAppear` is it correct. This is a problem because I need to update the size of elements in the keyboard based on the available width and height. Right now I am handling this by detecting the frame size in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, which is called several times before it is correct. This works, but the user can see the elements changing size in the keyboard - the frame is not correct until after it has been presented to the user. This is also a problem because I need to update the scroll position once the elements are their correct size, so I'm forced to delay that until `viewDidAppear`. This isn't a great user experience with things jumping around after it's been presented.

Is there any way I could know the height and width of the keyboard earlier in the life cycle so I can set the size of the elements before they become visible to the user?

I am using a XIB to create the keyboard interface which utilizes Auto Layout. This is how I add it to the keyboard:

```
let keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)
let keyboardInterface = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

keyboardInterface.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

self.inputView.addSubview(keyboardInterface)

let verticalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[keyboardInterface]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["keyboardInterface": keyboardInterface, "view": view]) as! [NSLayoutConstraint]
let horizontalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[keyboardInterface]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["keyboardInterface": keyboardInterface]) as! [NSLayoutConstraint]

self.inputView.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
self.inputView.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
```

Comment: I am surprised you are not getting correct frames and bounds in viewWillAppear. They are guaranteed to be loaded by the time it is called. Are you getting 0 or other numbers? What numbers are you getting?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 I get 0 in `viewDidLoad` and the values of the size of the `UIView` specified in the XIB file in `viewWillAppear` before I finally get the correct size in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Isn't that what your constraints are doing? you have a zero distance from all sides so keyboard interface view would have the size of the view it is in (the XIB)?

Comment: No, the view is actually larger in the XIB in width and the height isn't the same either. The keyboard is forced to be the default system keyboard size (because I'm not modifying its height in Auto Layout although I could).